# How to create a explorer alike column in outlook having drag and drop facility?

Tags: c#, outlook

I want to have an explorer like column (something like list of emails in inbox) that comes with Outlook. In this column I want to populate list of data, where I could drop any email from the my inbox list.

[image]

How should I proceed to achieve this, any hints OR links where I could move forward as I am new to Visual Studio development. I went through couple of tutorials where I can design a form (with an icon coming at the tool bar and it opens a different window on click), but I am wondering if it is possible to have a form visible within the same explorer window (on the right hand side ) with a flexibility to show OR hide it.

The reason I want it on the same window is because I want to achieve drag and drop functionality for my emails in inbox to my custom list data in my new column. e.g. associating email X and Y to process Z in column C.

Thanks

Comment: The title is not meant to be a keyword list, that's what the tags are for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to develop an Outlook add-in with an adjacent form. Unfortunately the Outlook extensibility model doesn't provide anything for that out of the box, so you need to use Windows API functions or use third-party software to get the form shown in the Explorer window. You can read more about the adjacent forms on the [Creating Adjacent Windows In Outlook](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-Adjacent-Windows-00090e4a) page where you can also find the sample code. Or may consider using [Advanced Outlook view and form regions](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/outlook-regions-basics.php) as an alternative.

FYI Command bars were deprecated and are not used any longer. The Fluent UI is used instead.